# How website hide api response?

Tags: web-application, rest, api

I build a web application and get data via REST API.
eg: `https://mywebapi.com/product/{productId}`
then I get json response and use the json data response in my web page `https://myweb.com/product/{productId}`

It is pretty obvious that I can see the call and get the response json from browser network inspect/fiddler.

But when I visit the product page of website like `Amazon` and `Klook`, I am not able to find the request and response as of above-mentioned. I am expecting they are implementing REST api method as well for getting data (correct me if they do not).

My question is: 
1) Where the response is located? Because I inspect through all the request and response when I visit the product page and I can't find the relevant request and response for the product data. 
2) If it is hidden, how website like Amazon and Klook hide it?

Amazon Link: [Click here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BAHF8W)
Klook Link: [Click here](https://www.klook.com/activity/524-disneyland-gourmet-meal-voucher-hong-kong/)

Comment: can you provide a link to a page where you expect such a request to originate? servers can spit out ready-to-render html; not everything is an API yet...

Comment: @dandavis i have updated the both with  both amazon and klook link

Comment: i see several backend API interactions firing on that amazon page, they are not hidden; stuff like navigation links, reviews, menus, deal status. etc...

Comment: @dandavis  which request link are you seeing? Taking review as example, i do not see any request with the review response. I have inspect through each and every request and response with chrome. I don't see any response that include the reviews text on that page, and neither on the product details. It could be good if you can screenshot the request response.

Comment: They could well be using websockets, which would be in a different place in the inspector

Comment: It is not possible to hide network traffic.  If you aren't finding it it merely means you aren't looking in the correct place.